# PHP prevent SIGTERM to bubble to proc_open process

Tags: php, process, signals

**Original question (Send SIGTERM to child on CTRL+C and parent should wait for it to close). See update below!**

I have a PHP script (see below) starting a process and tailing it's output. This process keeps running until I ask PHP to stop by hitting CTRL+C or sending a SIGTERM signal to the PHP scripts (pid). At this point PHP decides to kill the process started by proc_open immediately instead of closing it gracefully and waiting on it before closing itself, how can I achieve this?

I tried a few things like adding `pcntl_waitpid($childPid)` etc, but so far obviously no luck.

```php
<?php

// Handle close signals (like CTRL+C).
function closeChildApplication(int $signal) {
    // ???
}

// Async signals instead of declare(TICKS=1) PHP 7.1+
pcntl_async_signals(true);
pcntl_signal(SIGTERM, 'closeChildApplication', false);
pcntl_signal(SIGINT, 'closeChildApplication', false);

// Create process.
$descriptors = [
    0 => ['pipe', 'r'],
    1 => ['pipe', 'w'],
    2 => ['pipe', 'w']
];
$proc = proc_open('<command-to-run>', $descriptors, $pipes);
if (!is_resource($proc)) {
    throw new \RuntimeException('Could not execute <command-to-run>.');
}

// Not sending any data to child, so close STDIN immediately.
fclose($pipes[0]);

// Non blocking mode.
stream_set_blocking($pipes[1], false);
stream_set_blocking($pipes[2], false);

do {
    $status = proc_get_status($proc);

    $data = '';
    while (!feof($pipes[1]) && false !== ($line = fgets($pipes[1]))) {
        $data .= $line;
    }
    if (!empty(trim($data))) {
        // STDOUT logic here.
    }

    $data = '';
    while (!feof($pipes[2]) && false !== ($line = fgets($pipes[2]))) {
        $data .= $line;
    }
    if (!empty(trim($data))) {
        // STDERR logic here.
    }

    sleep(1);
} while ($status['running']);

// Not running anymore, close resource.
fclose($pipes[1]);
fclose($pipes[2]);
proc_close($proc);
```

**UPDATE** It seems PHP *is waiting* for child to be closed but the program in question is not handling the SIGTERM and SIGINT very well and kills itself immediately instead of cleaning up and closing. I found out that I can send QUIT command to the programs STDIN to trigger a clean shutdown.

But the problem I now face is that when PHP receives a SIGTERM/SIGINT signal this is also send to program opened with proc_open (so it bubbles down to the child).

By playing around a bit if found out we can do `pcntl_signal(SIGTERM, SIG_IGN, false);` which causes PHP to ignore the signal and prevents it from being send to the child. But now I don't know if a signal is send.

Another way is to do:

```php
function closeChildApplication(int $signal) {
    // do nothing in here.
}

pcntl_signal(SIGTERM, 'closeChildApplication', false);
```

In which case PHP ignores the signal and keeps running but the child receives it and is killed. Anyone who knows how to prevent a signal to bubble to child or ignore the signals but for example in below while to check if any signals are received?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after a few days of puzzling around with this issue if found out that proc_open seems to sort of inherit PHP's setting regarding the SIG_IGN signal.

When saying `pcntl_signal(SIGTERM, SIG_IGN, false);` PHP and process opened by proc_open both ignore this signal.

When saying `pcntl_signal(SIGTERM, function(){ echo 'test'; }, false);` PHP echoes 'test' and continues to run, however the process opened by proc_open is also receiving SIGTERM and closes itself.

But interestingly when I do:

```php
// Ignore all signals:
pcntl_signal(SIGTERM, SIG_IGN, false);

// Start program:
proc_open('command // etc');

// Install signal handler for PHP:
pcntl_signal(SIGTERM, function(){ echo 'test'; }, false);
```

PHP echoes 'test' on receiving the signal, but the process started with proc_open is not doing anything with the SIGTERM signal which indicates to me that SIG_IGN is inherited by proc_open.

This is exactly what I need right now, but is kinda weird that this is the only way to tell proc_open to ignore some signals, not sure if this is intended behavior or a PHP bug.